# Adding custom Images in WooCommerce mini-cart based on quantity / category

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce, cart

Likely a basic one that I'm just a little way from solving. 
Essentially I'm building an online store selling beer bottles in increments of 12 per case, with the option to a mix any of 7 different beers. At the moment, I've enabled the mini cart to show a case fill up - bottle by bottle - with each bottle added, which is based on cart total.

```
<?php if( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 0){ 
    echo '<img src="***image-with-0-bottles" alt="icon" />';
} 

elseif( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 1){ 
    echo '<img src="***image-with-1-bottle.png" alt="icon" />';
}

elseif( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 2){ 
    echo '<img src="***image-with-2-bottle2.png" alt="icon" />';
}
```

etc and so on and so on.

The above is probably an unnecessarily convoluted way to do it, but the main concern is that the above needs to happen only when one particular category is added to the cart ie. only for single bottles. If any other category is added to the basket, I'd want the images to stay the same and only change if a 'single-bottle' is added.

Bit new. Bit stuck. Bit PHP-poor! I've tried a number of things I've read but I just don't really have the knowledge to truly know where I stand. Any help would be so so welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you display the code for the mini-cart template, you have this regarding the thumbnails `(line 38)`:

```
$thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

It means that you can manipulate the mini cart thumbnails.

But for your special product category, as it's based on total cart count you will get the same image on all items for this product category.

Here is a example of that code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', 'custom_cart_item_thumbnail', 10, 3 );
function custom_cart_item_thumbnail( $thumbnail, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ){
    // Only for Mini Cart
    if( is_cart() ) return $thumbnail;

    $product = $cart_item['data'];
    $product_id = $product->get_id();
    $cart_item_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

    // Set here your product category like 'case-dozen'
    if( has_term( 'case-dozen', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ){
        // Total cart item count based
        if ( 0 == $cart_item_count )
            $thumbnail = '<img src="/image-with-0-bottles.png" alt="icon" />';
        elseif ( 1 == $cart_item_count )
            $thumbnail = '<img src="/image-with-1-bottle.png" alt="icon" />';
        elseif ( 2 == $cart_item_count )
            $thumbnail = '<img src="/image-with-2-bottle2.png" alt="icon" />';
    }
    return $thumbnail;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This should work.

Comment: Hi @loictheaztec major thanks for coming back to me. This certainly works on the thumbail images. I've tried to use some of the references in my scenario and no such luck. The image that changes based on the cart contents is within mini-cart.php but not a thumbnail. For example, here's how it looks with three bottles in the cart: http://i67.tinypic.com/2yu0pxd.png The functionality all works - but restricting the changing of this 'bottle case' section to 1 particular category is what I'm struggling with. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Infact, you may as well see the actual page to be clearer: http://fcb.eb8.myftpupload.com/siop-shop/

Comment: So pleased with your help. Thank you very very much!